# How to reuse a Result after ? operator?

Tags: rust, error-handling

The following does not compile. How can I make this work?

```
let file = File::open(&args.path)?;
let reader = BufReader::new(file);

for line in reader.lines() {
    if line?.contains(&args.pattern) {
        println!("{}", line?);
    }
}
```

Here's the error message:

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `line`
  --> src/main.rs:20:28
   |
18 |     for line in reader.lines() {
   |         ---- move occurs because `line` has type `Result<String, std::io::Error>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
19 |         if line?.contains(&args.pattern) {
   |            ----- `line` moved due to this method call
20 |             println!("{}", line?);
   |                            ^^^^ value used here after move
```

Answer (score 5):

In your example `line` is a `Result`, which is moved when you use `?` (but do we really need the `Result` after you've unwrapped its contents???). To alleviate your problem, let's *shadow* the value of the `Result` in a local variable of the same name.

```
for line in reader.lines() {
    let line = line?;
    if line.contains(&args.pattern) {
        println!("{}", line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This was my initial solution, too.  But as a developer coming from numerous other languages without Rust's ownership model, creating an extra local variable just felt wrong somehow.

Comment: I understand, it seems clunky at first. I believe (but am not positive) that when we shadow a variable by using the same name the previous value is dropped from memory, so it's not even incurring a performance hit; we're just making the borrow checker happy :)